# Steerer tube shims for quill stem?

Tags: fork, steerer, shim

My current stem is 25.4 mm in diameter. It's way too low and long. It's a threaded fork.

I have a nice quill stem adaptor that's 22.2 in diameter that would be nice to use.

Are there any shims to go from 22.2 to 25.4 and is it worth it?

I found [some from Problem solvers](http://problemsolversbike.com/products/cockpit/steerer_tube_shims_-_25242) but it seems to be for threadless stems only.

what would you do? would a shim be safe here or is it a no-do?

UPDATE: I found a shim and installed it. It works really good. Much better than my old crappy quill stem.

Comment: You probably could use a shim, but you'd have to make your own, and I can't find any 1/8" brass sheet online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threadless quill stem adaptors do commonly come with a shim, so that they can be used with either size steerer, e.g. 
http://harriscyclery.net/product/velowerx-universal-stem-adapter-quill-to-threadless-5423.htm

I've never seen such a shim sold separately, but a search shows up https://www.amazon.co.uk/Alloy-Aluminium-Quill-Adapter-Quillstem/dp/B00K7ECRLO, which is currently unavailable, but was sold at some time, so you *might* find one.

Comment: Here's one: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1-to-1-22-2mm-to-25-4mm-Handlebar-Quill-Stem-Shim-for-Bike-Cycle-/401371822981?hash=item5d739ffb85:g:MCsAAOSwkNZUp~qh

Comment: (Just buying a new quill stem, or a new oversize adaptor, would still be a neater solution, so the fact that a shim would work doesn't necessarily mean it's worthwhile.)

Comment: Thanks! I also found this one https://www.rosebikes.se/product/detail/aid:27776 I'll se if it works.

Comment: Have been running it for a while now and it seems to work really good. So far no problems.